# can not set text to JLabel when select item in JComboBOX

Tags: java, swing, events, user-interface

This code shows me syntax error (excepted "{") but I think something else is wrong.

```
 public class CircleController extends JPanel {
   private JComboBox product1=new JComboBox(Application.listArray);
   private JLabel jlb1=new JLabel();
   //..........some fields more
   // constructor....
 public CircleController() {

  // Panel to group labels
JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
//..........some labels....
//another panel
JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
panel2.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,4,20,20 ));
panel2.add(product1);
panel2.add(jlb1);
```

and part of code with error

```
  //product1 is combobox, jlbt is label wich I want to set when I selected item from  combobox

    product1.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e)  { // in this line shows me an error

        (Product name:Application.manu) {
             if ((String)product1.getSelectedItem()==name.getName()){
                 String price1=Double.toString(name.getPrice());
                jlb1.setText(price1);
             }
        }

    if (model != null){
        model.setProduct((String)product1.getSelectedItem());}}

});
```

program worked fine with this code

```
    product1.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) { 

    if (model != null){
        model.setProduct((String)product1.getSelectedItem());}}

});
```

but when I add this statement (this statement is checked and it is good)

```
   (Product name:Application.manu) {
             if ((String)product1.getSelectedItem()==name.getName()){
                 String price1=Double.toString(name.getPrice());
                jlb1.setText(price1);
             }
        }
```

inside `product1.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {....` program shows error

Do I have to add another `ItemListener` to set label?

Comment: for better help sooenr post an  [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable, just about `JFrame`, `JComboBox` and `JLabel`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compile error is actually related to this line:

```
(Product name:Application.manu) {
```

It looks like a foreach, so it should be:

```
for (Product name:Application.manu) {
```